# RabbitMQ Priority Queues not working in MULE

Tags: rabbitmq, mule, amqp, priority-queue, mule-component

I'm trying to use the Priority Queues mechanism provided by RabbitMQ within MULE ESB.

I have created a queue with `x-max-priority = 3` and in a new Mule Proyect, I've set 3 AMQP:connectors, one for each priority, like this:

```
<amqp:connector 
    name="amqpLocalhostConnector0"
    host="${amqp.host}"
    port="${amqp.port}"
    fallbackAddresses="${amqp.fallbackAddresses}"
    virtualHost="${amqp.virtualHost}"
    username="${amqp.username}"
    password="${amqp.password}"
    priority="0"
    ackMode="AMQP_AUTO"
    prefetchCount="${amqp.prefetchCount}" />

/* The values within ${} are taken from a properties file.
 * Priorities are: "0", "1", "2" */
```

Then, there is a simple flow that sends messages every second to the queue containing the priority as a string in the body, besides the property `priority` used in the connector.

```
<flow name="rabbitmqFlow1" doc:name="rabbitmqFlow1">

    <poll frequency="1000" doc:name="Poll">
        <set-payload value="PRIORITY 1" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </poll>

    <amqp:outbound-endpoint 
        exchangeName="amq.direct"
        routingKey="priority"
        connector-ref="amqpLocalhostConnector0">
    </amqp:outbound-endpoint>

</flow>
```

I manually repeat this proccess alternating the priority used by each message batch. This way, my queue has several messages with different priorities mixed.

Now, if I manually dequeue messages using the Get Message(s) button in the Management UI, they are delivered according the priority: first those with priority 2, then those with priority 1 and finally those with priority 0.

**The problem is** when I try to get the messages using a `amqp:inbound-endpoint` component in MULE.
Here is another simple flow that just gets the messages from the priority queue and shows what's the content of each one.

```
<flow name="rabbitmqFlow2" doc:name="rabbitmqFlow2">

    <amqp:inbound-endpoint 
        queueName="priority"/>

    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>

    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

</flow>
```

Here the messages are obtained in the order they were sended to the queue and not according their priorities.

What can I do to read the messages from the queue respecting priorities?

Comment: Could it be because `"if such a hungry consumer connects to an empty queue to which messages are subsequently published, the messages may not spend any time at all waiting in the queue. In this case the priority queue will not get any opportunity to prioritise them."` ? (from https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html )

Comment: @DavidDossot first I manually send the messages to the queue to get several messages with different priorities mixed. Then I execute the second flow, which reads the messages from the queue. They're not executed simultaneously, so I can discard that problem.